# Remove page number box in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, pdf, uiwebview

I'm opening a PDF file with `UIWebView` and once I'm starting to scroll down, it shows the page number in a box and I don't want to see it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the UIWebView pdf behaviour, use something else to open your pdf :)

There's a [demo project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281) from Apple that shows you how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, it's an option, but it's kind of complicating things,
maybe there is a way to play a little bit with the WebView?